# Clear previously set headers php

Tags: php, http-headers

I would like to know if its possible to clear the current information stored in header_list()

```
if(headers_sent()){
    foreach(headers_list() as $header){
        header_remove($header);
    }
}
var_dump(headers_list());
```

Comment: After headers have been sent?

Comment: If headers are sent, not much point removing them (if you can), because... they're already sent.

Comment: possible according to [php.net](http://php.net/header_remove) , but only from version 5.3.0 - and you can even remove the headers generated by php itself

Comment: and this would probably only work until any bit of non-headers output has been made... (since once you flush anything, the headers already gone out to the browser)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`headers_sent`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) indicates that it is too late to remove headers. They're already **sent**. Hence the name of the function.

What you want is to specifically check if the headers have *not* been sent yet. Then you know it's safe to modify them.

```
if (!headers_sent()) {
  foreach (headers_list() as $header)
    header_remove($header);
}
```

Comment: `foreach` is no longer needed. See my answer

Answer (score 12):

To remove them all it's pretty simple:

```
if ( ! headers_sent() ) {
    header_remove();
}
```

No looping required. If you don't pass a parameter to `header_remove`, it removes all headers set by PHP.

Answer (score 6):

You can remove the headers only if they're not already sent. If `headers_sent` is `true`, the headers have already gone out and you cannot unset them anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Once the header is sent we can not clear it. The best solution for it is to turn on output_buffering in the php.ini file.

```
output_buffering = On
```

But if the header is not sent then you can clear it via header_remove(); function.

Comment: And then you can recall them and delete ?

Comment: @GeorgeTiganila Yes